# Stop content from overflowing a fixed div?

Tags: css

I have a div with positons `fixed` inside a fixed width parent, yet it's content overflows.

How can I contain the content to the `fixed` div?

```
<div style="width: 400px;">
    <div style="position: fixed;">
        <p>Some long p text which is currently overflowing....</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to scroll it, wrap it, make font size smaller so it fits or some combination? Could you put up a working snippet so we can easily see the problem for ourselves and help you

Answer (score 1):

You won't see a good result setting the position to fixed. Because the div that is inside the parent is position fixed, and it's not true. It's not like position relative and absolute.

You can fix it like this:

You must set a fixed width, e.g. the parent is 200px and so you have to set the width to 200px on the second div. Remember that if you set it to 100%, it will cover the whole page, which is a mistake.

```html
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid red">
  <div style="position: fixed; width: 200px;">
    <p>Some long p text which is currently overflowing....</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Here are some overflow properties this will help you**

```
div{
  overflow: scroll;
}

div{
  overflow: hidden;
}

div{
  overflow: auto;
}

div{
  overflow: visible;
}
```

**Maybe this code will help you check**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   
<style>
    .ex1 {
      background-color: lightblue;
      width: 110px;
      height: 110px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
    </style>
    
    <div class="ex1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

**Verifiy my answer if this help you.**

Comment: I don;t want to hide it, I want to wrap it.

Comment: so use ```overflow: scroll``` or other overflow properties.

Comment: first clear what you actually want? ```scroll```,```visible```,```auto```